# Read detailed variant configuration from sales order

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to read variant configurations from sales orders.

At the moment I use the BAPI `BAPI_SALESORDER_GETDETAILBOS` or `BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST`.

But I need some more information.

For example:

I got a car and I need all single parts which are included in that car (all material numbers).

Is there a BAPI, RFC or internal function module to get those pieces of information?

Comment: Looks like you need some info on material. Look for BAPIs in Material Management section.

Comment: I already did. I found this bapi (CS_BOM_EXPL_MAT_V2) but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Not sure if this will work for you but have a look at BAPI_MATERIAL_GETCOMPONENTS. Have a look at business object BUS1001001 in TA BAPI or SWO1.

Comment: Will take a look at this one. I also found an interesting BAPI: BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST This one delivers also information about configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it. Will use BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST for this purpose.